# Securing /tmp on OpenVZ

Tags: mount, tmp, openvz

```
/tmp should be mounted as a separate filesystem with the noexec,nosuid options set
/var/tmp should either be symlinked to /tmp or mounted as a filesystem
/dev/shm is not mounted with the noexec,nosuid options (currently: none). You should modify the mountpoint in /etc/fstab for /dev/shm with those options and remount
```

This is an OpenVZ Server and I don't know how to fix those issues.

How do I make /tmp ect... safe on OpenVZ?

This for the guest. can this be done on the host?

Comment: On the host node or the guest container?

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/43976/26001)

Comment: guest. can this be done on the host?

Comment: Please don't vote to close, the cross-posted question on security.se has been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can secure from [centos secure tmp how to](http://pingbin.com/2011/06/centos-secure-tmp/), then change it according to `shared memory (shm)` and other `shared directories`.

Above solution is first solution, but if you don't have any information, you can use second solution: OpenVZ make an instance from each resource but VMWare doesn't create it, you can use VMWare.

[This post](http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=47086&) is very good.